# Origen de "patán"

Tags: etimología, historia, español-neutral, dle

El DLE recoge [**patán**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S7jDPex) como:

> De *pata*<sup>1</sup>.
>   1. m. y f. coloq. Aldeano o rústico.
>   2. m. y f. coloq. Persona zafia y tosca. U. t. c. adj. *Gente patana.*

y [**pata**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S71hGRM) como:

> De or. inc.
>   1. f. Pie y pierna de los animales.
>   2. f. Pie de un mueble.
>   3. f. En las prendas de vestir, cartera, golpe.
>   4. f. coloq. Pierna de una persona.
>   5. m. y f. coloq. *Bol., Cuba y Perú.* amigo (‖ persona que tiene amistad).

pero se me escapa la conexión entre las palabras. ¿Qué relación hay entre  **pata** y **patán** para considerar que *patán* proceda de *pata*?

Comment: ¿Puede ser que se deba a que "solo sirve para sostener"? Porque es una tarea "simple", y porque los campesinos sostenían a los señoritos... se me ocurre...

Comment: ¡Muy buena pregunta!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El *Diccionario de Autoridades* (tomo O-R, 1737) nos da directamente la respuesta:

> PATAN. s.m. El hombre záfio, tosco y campesino. Llámase assi, porque ordinariamente tiene grandes patas ò pies, y las hace mayores con el calzado tosco que trahe.

Es ciertamente una voz con solera, ya que el primer caso del CORDE se remonta a 1550:

> *¿Este no es el palomino? ¡Ha, don villano patán!*
>
> Juan Pastor, "Tragedia de la castidad de Lucrecia", c 1550 (España).